# Agile Web Development with Rails 4 - Iteration F - Decrement action -> reuse of destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the book *"Agile Web Development with Rails 4"* and did the Playtime-exercise creating a decrement-button to decrement the quantity of an item in the virtual shopping cart. It should be deleted, if the quantity is just one.

Though this is an easy task, I worry about code duplication, because I have a destroy action in my controller which deletes an item with AJAX. If I change this later on, I don't want to change it for the decrementation, too. Beside that I have to copy the whole AJAX, that I'm using for deletion to the decrmentation. 
I would like to use this method with all it's AJAX and so on to handle the case when it's the last item of that kind in the cart to delete it.

A bit like this (pseudocode):

```
IF last_item_of_that_kind
  execute destroy_action
ELSE
  decrement
  forward_to ...
END
```

Does anybody has an idea how to nicely achieve it to just "forward" to the destroy action in that case?

**LineItemController:**

```
# DELETE /line_items/1
# DELETE /line_items/1.json
def destroy
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  @line_item.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to cart_url(@cart), notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

# POST /line_items
# POST /line_items.json
def decrement
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  @line_item = LineItem.find_by_id(params[:id])

  # did it in the cart-model first, but that does not allow to redirect correctly
  if @line_item.quantity > 1
    @line_item.quantity -= 1
    if @line_item.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to cart_url(@cart), notice: 'Line item was successfully decreased.' }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.json { head :ok }
      end
    end
  else
    # did not find a way to call the destroy-mehtod with post, to avoid code-duplicates
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cart_url(@cart), notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

For sure it would be nicer to handle the decrementation itself in the cart model, but then I would need to check the values, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the logic of whether to decrement or destroy in the model, which will simplify your controller.

Note the use of bang `!` methods which bypass validation. `save` will fail if `@line_item` is in an invalid state.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  def decrement_or_destroy!
    quantity > 1 ? decrement!(:quantity) : destroy!
  end
end
```

So in your controller, your code would be:

```
# dry controller actions further
before_action :set_cart_line_item, only: [:destroy, :decrement]    

def destroy
  @line_item.destroy

  destroy_line_item_response
end

def decrement
  @line_item.decrement_or_destroy!

  if @line_item.destroyed?
    destroy_line_item_response
  else
    decrement_line_item_response
  end
end

private
def set_cart_line_item
  # assume that all line items should be accessed through cart
  # don't want people posting line_item ids belonging to other carts
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.find_by_id(params[:id])
end

def decrement_line_item_response
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to cart_url(@cart), notice: 'Line item was successfully decreased.' }
    format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end

def destroy_line_item_response
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to cart_url(@cart), notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.js do 
      @current_item = @line_item
      render file: 'line_items/destroy' 
    end
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it good practice to call controller-methods in the model? Why should I want the save-method to bypass validation? I don't see a case for this. For the create methods it's necessary and at the point of decrementation or deletion it should be valid though. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Klumbe: `#decrement!` and `#destroy!` are both model methods belonging to `ActiveRecord::Base`, not the controller. If your `LineItem` has invalid data (eg. price set to `"100"` for an integer field instead of `100`), it will always get deleted instead of decremented.

Comment: Oh ok, but if they belong to the model, it does not help me with my problem concerning the reuse of my controller-method (especially the redirects, AJAX and so on), though it's a useful information. Do you want to say that it's not possible to delete an invalid `LineItem` without the bang-operator? In my opinion it will be deleted anyhow (in any case ´quantity <= 1`). As the item has been persisted before I don't see why validation should fail or how the price should change to a wrong type if I don't explicitly do that (which I don't).

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the inner nested `if`. Delete will work, but if your `LineItem` is invalid, the `save` call will fail, which means `quantity` will not be reduced despite rendering a successful action. I'll update the answer to include reusing the `respond_to` block.

Comment: Thanks for your very nice answer! I think that hits the spot. I think the `save` action is still ok without the bang because the `LineItem` isn't modified except it's quantity. So if it has been valid on it's first save, it should be still valid when it will be decremented. I haven't tried your answer yet, but I will try it ASAP. One more (maybe stupid question): Do I have to implement the `decrement!`and `destroy!`methods in the model? I think yes because it can not know what to decrement, right?

Comment: Oh and something else (actually this is why I haven't used methods just for the response like `decrement_line_item_respone`): I think this will not find the right Javascript file on it's own (destroy.js.erb), because it's not coming from inside the `destroy`method of the controller. I have tried it before and that did not work (reasonably I think).

Comment: The bang indicates that it will raise an exception if it fails - good practice to follow convention. For the JS partial, you can explicitly call `render`, eg.`format.js { @current_item = @line_item; render :destroy }`. Not sure about your view directory structure, you might need to specify `render file: 'line_items/destroy'`

Comment: `decrement!` and `destroy!` are part of ActiveRecord - you don't need to implement them. Also better to bypass validation if you don't need it - this might come back to bite you as an unexpected bug if you add additional state to `LineItem` in future.

Comment: Thanks! I think all these tweaks together let it look much better and stops me writing so much code duplicates. I edited your answer with the changes you suggested and added an argument that was missing on the `decrement!`method (this is why I thought that it's a custom method). It should be ´decrement!(:quantity)`. I will accept your answer as soon as the edit is reviewed, because it will then pretty much nail the question. Thanks again!

Comment: the edit has been rejected because "it does not make sense as an edit", so for completeness: could you please edit it by yourself? I think that would be nice for everybody trying to solve a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks! It now is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way in some code presented a few pages later in the book (page 168 for whom is interested).
One can call `LineItem.destroy(@line_item)` where needed.

So in general: `ControllerName.method(parameters)`.

I think this is a much better approach then rewriting the whole redirect.

The decrement-method would look like this now:

```
# POST /line_items
# POST /line_items.json
def decrement
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  @line_item = LineItem.find_by_id(params[:id])

  # did it in the cart-model first, but that does not allow to redirect correctly
  if @line_item.quantity > 1
    @line_item.quantity -= 1
    if @line_item.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to cart_url(@cart), notice: 'Line item was successfully decreased.' }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
       format.json { head :ok }
      end
    end
  else
    # call the destroy-method and run all associated
    LineItem.destroy(@line_item)
  end
end
```

So now the AJAX-part can be separated and code-duplication is avoided.

Just for your information: The decreasing of the quantity should take place inside the model, but I found it easier to handle the two cases this way.

Comment: My attention was drawn back to this post by a notification. Wonder whether your solution would still remain the same with the passage of time?

Comment: @fylooi: As already mentioned in the solution, I would move all model-actions to the model and just return the {-1, 0, 1} or similar codes to signal the calling method that the item has been decremented, deleted or there has been an error. But apart from that I guess it would stay pretty much the same.